# is it possible to add table bootstrap inside angular accordion

Tags: angular

I wanted to know if it is possible to put a table inside an accordion like the example below:

```
<mat-expansion-panel hideToggle>
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>
      This is the expansion title
    </mat-panel-title>
    <mat-panel-description>
      This is a summary of the content
    </mat-panel-description>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
<ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
  <table> queria saber se é possível adiocionar essa tabela aqui</table>
 </ng-template>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Comment: Yes. Feel free to give it a try.